# "Nested" relationships php activerecord?

Tags: php, phpactiverecord

I'm struggling with relationships in PHPActiveRecord.

I have these tables:

**User_group**
id, name, ...

**Seller:**
id, group_id ...

**Order:**
seller_id, id ...

And I want to be able to do like User_group->orders, but can't make it work.

My initial thought went like this (nevermind syntax/spelling):

User_group

```
$has_many = array(
    array('sellers'),
    array('orders', 'through' => 'sellers')
);
```

Seller:

```
$belongs_to = array(
    array('user_group');
);
$has_many = array(
    array('orders');
);
```

Order:

```
$belong_to = array(
    array('seller'),
    array('user_group', 'through' => 'seller')
);
```

What am I making wrong?

THANKS!